# Jquery append a table inside of a td breaks

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, append

This one has me stumped... there is a apparently something that breaks in jquery when I try appending a table inside of a another table td or th... hopefully there is someone with an answer

This is simplified version of what I'm trying to do but should get the point across

Example

```
<table id="myTable">
    <tr>
        <td>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>

<script>
    $('#myTable td:last').append('<table><tr><td>Cell1</td><td>Cell2</td></tr></table>');
</script>
```

when you do this jquery will automatically take the rest of the table and insert it into the "td" instead of just inserting the table I appended. Its like it doesnt see the closing tag so everything from the rest of the table gets added to the "td"

Is there a work around or am I just doing this wrong?

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Can't reproduce the issue: http://jsfiddle.net/2YjXu/

Comment: Well im blown away that for some reason the code works in jsfiddle and not on my site... ill see if I can reproduce it breaking in jsfiddle.. thank you for checking

Comment: Well I figured it out... the problem is that I was inserting a table with another "tbody" tag in it so the next time I want to append something the the original tbody tag it actually appends to both the main and the previous table i inserted in the other element... no to find the work around

Comment: Use a more specific selector, like maybe `#myTable > tbody` for the outer `tbody`.

Comment: Your the man!!!... very clean solution.. that totally fixed my problem.. I didn't know that jquery ">" select option even existed.. Thank you!

Comment: Glad I could help. `>` is actually used in css, which jQuery mostly mirrors.